# Docker-compose start fail

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to install and use docker-compose for the first time on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, but I am failing :))

I have installed docker-compose via pip using

When I try to run `docker-compose up` I get this error trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    from . import errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/errors.py", line 10, in <module>
    from docker.errors import APIError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .api import APIClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .client import APIClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .build import BuildApiMixin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .utils import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .. import tls
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/tls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .transport import SSLAdapter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/transport/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ssladapter import SSLAdapter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/transport/ssladapter.py", line 22, in <module>
    urllib3.connection.match_hostname = match_hostname
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connection'
```

Eggs versions:

```
$pip freeze | grep -e urllib3 -e requests -e docker-py                                    
docker-pycreds==0.2.1
requests==2.13.0
urllib3==1.14
```

I tried to export PYTHONPATH like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Comment: 1.14 is a very old version. Try to upgrade it using `pip install urllib3 --upgrade` And you can check whether you have more than one urllib3 in your dist-packages (For example, try `import urllib3 ; urllib3`. I think it should be in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3`

Comment: I upgraded my urllib3 version to 1.20. It works if I do `import urllib3 ; urllib3` but docker-compose does not start :(

Comment: I'm sorry to have mistaken you. 1.14 is not that old. My version of urllib3 is 1.7 in which there is not connection module. It was added since 1.8 (However, my docker-compose works well. My 'requests' version is 2.2.1)

Comment: What the ssladapter uses is request.packages.urllib3 (You can open the ssladapter.py to check how it imports.)  So you should make sure `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3` exists and connection.py exists in this folder. In my machine, it exists.

Comment: Can you include your docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have more than one packages with different version.

request and urllib3 can both exist in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

In ssladapter.py, request.packages.urllib3 is priorly imported according:

`try:
    import requests.packages.urllib3 as urllib3
except ImportError:
    import urllib3`

If your requests.packages.urllib3 is too old, error will be raised.

So you have two ways to fix this problem

1. copy the newest urllib3 into requests/packages
2. remove the urllib3 in requests/packages so that docker-compose will use the urllib3 from pythonpath (your latest urllib3)

(You can get the path of requests by the interactive console:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests
<module 'requests' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.pyc'>
```

)